# can not understanding declaration of constructor of wrapper class

Tags: c++

Below is a wrapper class I found in the stackoverflow.

```
class int_ptr_wrapper
{
public:
    int_ptr_wrapper(int value = 0) :
    mInt(new int(value))
    {}

    // note! needs copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator!

    ~int_ptr_wrapper()
    {
        delete mInt;
    }

private:
    int* mInt;
};
```

I could not understand the meaning of declaration:

```
    int_ptr_wrapper(int value = 0) :
    mInt(new int(value))
    {}
```

Can you explain the meaning of this declaration in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor uses [initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in which you simply dynamically allocate memory for `mInt` variable.

That constructor is the same as this:

```
int_ptr_wrapper(int value = 0){
mInt = new int(value);
}
```